# SELECT one record and bind to text boxes

Tags: android, sqlite

this is my query

```
SELECT *
FROM articles
WHERE id >1
ORDER BY id ASC
LIMIT 1
```

[image]

my requirement is very simple. I just want to select only one record and bind to textViews . This is what I had done so far.

```
public Article oneRecord()
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT  * FROM articles WHERE id=3;", null);
    if(c.moveToFirst()){

            Article a= new Article();
            a.setId(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("id")));
            a.setImage_url(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("image_url")));
            a.setTitle(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("title")));
            a.setBody(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("body")));

    }
    return a;
}
```

Comment: Could you tell us why what you tried is not working ?

Comment: more code is expected

Comment: I can bind to a list with Adapter or listView . I updated my question please check

Comment: I do not know how to bind to a textView

Comment: what do you mean by bind to textview?

Comment: "SELECT TITLE FROM articles " -> Bind to textViewTitle.setText

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I have understood you problem correctly or not. However there is not special thing to do. Just update TextView after getting article from database.

```
Article a = getOneRecordFromDB();
titleView.setText(a.getTitle());
bodyView.setText(a.getBody());
```